# Including all terms in wordpress tax_query

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, loop, tax-query

I'm a little bit confused, why I can't include all the terms in tax_query automatically?

**My code:**

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'city',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( nyc, boston, london ),
         )
)
```

What If I've dozens of cities? Isn't it uncool to add them all manually?

Comment: Are you querying for posts? Or a custom post type? Meaning, will every post have a city assigned?

Comment: Yes I'm querying for posts using "query_posts".

Comment: That's totes uncool, maybe you don't need a Tax Query but instead just a parameter - `'taxonomy' => 'city'`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unless you have posts that *don't* have a city aren't you essentially querying all your posts? Anyway, Eric Holmes is correct that you should be using [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) in lieu of `query_posts()`.

That said, you can get a list of all the terms in a taxonomy and then use those values in your tax query.

```
// get all terms in the taxonomy
$terms = get_terms( 'city' ); 
// convert array of term objects to array of term IDs
$term_ids = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' );

// proceed with tax query
$args = array ('tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'city',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => $term_ids,
         )
)
);

$city_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks, I've selected `WP_Query`. Sounds better than query_posts(), because after all `query_posts()` is a function that return to `WP_Query`. And instead of term_ids I've used `'taxonomy' => 'city` to include everything in it.

Comment: No, I was wrong with `'taxonomy' => 'city'` only. Because it includes all the posts. I'll have to include `term_ids`. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the marked 'best answer', there is another way which might be even faster because we don't have to pull the terms and extract the names first.

This is achieved with a trick by using a non-existing operator (none of 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND', 'EXISTS' and 'NOT EXISTS'). For example, the string 'XXX' does the job and causes WP to not enter the cases during the query generation and therefore also the 0=1 concatenation is skipped.

(The cases are located in the function `get_sql_for_clause()` of the file class-wp-tax-query.php, where the allowed operators are checked via conditions and there is no 'else'.)
.

```
$args = array ('tax_query' => 
     array(
         array(
              'taxonomy' => 'city',
              //'field' => 'term_id', // <-- not needed, default
              //'terms' => $term_ids, // <-- not needed
              'operator' => 'XXX'     // Use a non-existing operator
         )
     )
);
```

Comment: This is especially useful if you want to grab posts that are not in _any_ taxonomy term. This actually saved me from over-complicating a query - either use a given term ID or allow all posts. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use `query_posts`. Create a new [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object instead.

Secondly, why would you need to add all the categories, if you are literally adding ALL categories? Would this not be the same as getting all posts? You can also specify which to NOT include. ie. "Everything but Chicago".